# Layout breaking when title of post breaks to next line or stacks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The layout is breaking when a verbose Post Title breaks into two lines and causes the element's height to increase.

The full Title must be viewable and thus cannot use something like `text-overflow: ellipsis` or `hidden`.

**Setting a `min-height` on the Title element cures the breakage.**

**Is this a naive approach or can it be improved?**

::Edit - Unable to add JS, only CSS.

---

### 2 Column Layout

[image: https://i.ibb.co/dtp37SP/Screenshot-2019-05-09-08-54-58.png]

---

### First container's height now larger than adjacent containers

[image]

Comment: you can solve this with help of javascript `.height()` if you need then comment

Comment: Appreciate the reply, as an edit to the post I included the usage of CSS only.

Answer (score 2):

please see this I have solved with CSS flex box

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap ;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.eachChid{
  width: 50%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;
} 
.eachChid img{
  width: 100%;
  
}
.wrapper{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="eachChid">
    <img class="irc_mi" src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/199508/original/file-20171215-17857-cns8cs.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&amp;q=45&amp;auto=format&amp;w=926&amp;fit=clip" >
    <p>over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="eachChid">
    <img class="irc_mi" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/afs-prod/media/afs:Medium:3700800010/775.jpeg" >
    <p>over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="eachChid">
    <img class="irc_mi" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9l0myTx3_TZEMQnJNvRnUJibglLctOfqLYmN9zfSrELVDfsG1" >
    <p>over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="eachChid">
    <img class="irc_mi" src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/199508/original/file-20171215-17857-cns8cs.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&amp;q=45&amp;auto=format&amp;w=926&amp;fit=clip" >
    <p>over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="eachChid">
    <img class="irc_mi" src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/199508/original/file-20171215-17857-cns8cs.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&amp;q=45&amp;auto=format&amp;w=926&amp;fit=clip" >
    <p>over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Fix this via css like:

`.box{
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: This will work if the Title can be hidden, as you can see in my description I cannot use the code you shared as the Title cannot be hidden.